# Navigation like this?

Tags: html, css

[image: Navigation example]

I have seen a navigation like this, and I absolutely love it. 
How would I go about by having this navigation, I currently have a template of a horizontal navigation which I use now, however no matter how much tweaking I do, it isn't coming close this design.

I also like where the logo is placed, Can you help me tweak my code?

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Catamaran', sans-serif;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-right: 50px;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
li {
  float: right;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: #666;
  padding: 60px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  color: #cc293f;
}
li a.active {
  color: #cc293f;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
```

```html
<html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Catamaran:600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />
<title>Sharpturn Network v2</title>
<header>
</header>
<ul>
  <img src="imgur.com/S17TggX">
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Upload</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#news">Support</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#contact">FAQs</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#about">Home</a>
  </li>
</ul>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This involves using float. The solution would look something like this:

```css
nav {
  background: black;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
}
#left-nav {
  float: left;
  color: white;
}
#right-nav {
  float: right;
}
#faqs {
  color: green;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  top: -10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div id='left-nav'>
    <img src='http://lorempixel.com/image_output/technics-q-g-60-40-3.jpg' alt='my image' />HYIP Templates
  </div>
  <div id='right-nav'>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='uploads.html'>Upload</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href='support.html'>Support</a>
      </li>
      <li id='faqs'><a href='faqs.html'>FAQs</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href='contact.html'>Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

As you can see above, instead of using divs for navigation, we can use the HTML5 semantic `nav` tag. We break it down into sections, one which will be the left side and the other the right. We assign each of these divs a `float` property.

In order to provide a background color to the nav element, we have to specify a height and width property.

By default `li` elements are block elements. To display them on the same line and remove line breaks, we set the display property to inline. In order to vertically center these list elements, we will use both the `line-height` and `top` properties.

An easier solution would be to use bootstrap's navbar classes.

We can replicate the black navbar with the `.navbar-inverse` class. We can replicate the left nav and right nav respectively with the `.nav-pull-left` and `.nav-pull-right` classes as well.

Comment: Hello Richard, I have copied your code and it's only showing the text of HYIP Templates, the navigation has disappeared along side the list, do you know why this is?

Comment: I understand, I will try to create a snippet. Also, as for the disappaerence, I was trying to make it look like the example. I forgot to include the background property for nav.

Comment: Thank you very much Richard

Comment: Do you need spacing to the right of the navbar?

Comment: Yes, so it's 3/4 of the way to the right, thank you.

Comment: Alright, I can't put that in the snippet, because it doesn't show a full-size snippet. But to do that, we would not use the `float:right` property, but instead the margin-right property. I think a value of 100 would do the trick

Comment: I tried margin-right however no luck so I used padd-left: 60%; which seemed fine, I'm having an issue where the page is active, I currently have 
#right-nav a:active {
 color: red;
}
and the html is 
 <li><a class="active" href='index.html'>Home</a></li>